# passing information from child class to parent, using dynamic classes in kvlang (Kivy)

Tags: kivy, dynamic-class

How can I pass information from a child class to its parent in kvlang, using dynamic classes?

I have the following simple kv code and Python code:

**kv:**

```
BoxLayout:
Label:
    id: label_id
    text: 'label'   
Button1:
    mylabel: label_id
    text: self.mylabel.text

<Button1@Button>:
```

**Python:**

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App

class Test2App(App):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test2App().run()
```

This works, making the Button's text the same as the label's text.

But what I want to do is set the Button's text in the parent class:

```
BoxLayout:
Label:
    id: label_id
    text: 'label'   
Button1:
    mylabel: label_id

<Button1@Button>:
    text: self.mylabel.text
```

This obviously leads to an error, because Button1 isn't aware of mylabel. But I want it to be. I know I can solve this by declaring a property in the Python file, but I'd rather have a solution inside the kv file alone.

Does anyone have an idea how to do that?

**EDIT:**

Interestingly, I'm able to pass information as a StringProperty. The following code works and I get the right text on my button:

```
BoxLayout:
Label:
    id: label_id
    text: 'label'   
Button1:
    my_label_text: label_id.text

<Button1@Button>:
    my_label_text: ''
    text: self.my_label_text
```

Does anyone know how I can pass the whole label (as an object) to the parent?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
BoxLayout:
    Label:
        id: label_id
        text: 'label'   
    Button1:
        mylabel: label_id

    <Button1@Button>:
        mylabel: None
        text: self.mylabel.text if self.mylabel is not None else ''
```

The `mylabel: None` creates a property automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem is that the information isn't passed from the child to the parent. What I get is a button with no text.

Comment: Ah, I think there's actually a mistake in my example, will fix later.

Comment: I just found out I'm able to pass information as a StringProperty. Please see the edited question